# Получить последнее значение из строки после символа

Tags: php

Приветствую.

есть к примеру строка:

> size=325 time=14:30 class=a size=360 time=12:10 class=a

Как мне получить из этой строки `12:10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "size=325 time=14:30 class=a size=360 time=12:10 class=a";
$array = explode(" ",$str);
foreach($array as $key =>$value){
  $v = explode("=",trim($value));
  $out[$v[0]] = $v[1];
}
echo $out['time'];
```

Можно с помощью регулярного выражения

```
preg_match_all("/time=([0-9]+)/",
"size=325 time=14:30 class=a size=360 time=12:10 class=a",
$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r(array_pop($out[1]));
```

Comment: А я вот подумал. Так не быстрее будет? $array = explode("size=",$str);

echo stristr(explode("=",trim(array_pop($array)))[1], ' ', true);

Comment: Даже так.   $array = explode("time=",$str);

echo stristr(array_pop($array), ' ', true);

Comment: Можно и через регулярные выражения сделать, но если нужно получить ТОЛЬКО значение последнего time, то да ваш вариант подходит, хоть для меня это какое то извращение

Comment: Ну мой вариант работает быстрей)

Comment: А как вы узнали что он работает быстрее? Тесты?

Comment: Добавил вариант решения через regexp

Comment: Да. Протестировал.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = explode("time=",$str);

 echo stristr(array_pop($array), ' ', true);
```